# HTML Canvas StrokeText LineWidth doubled with Noto Emoji

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make Emoji's appear the same for everyone in my web app. I'm using the Noto Emoji font to do so.

However, when I try to draw a piece of text with FillText and give it a stroke with StrokeText the stroke appear to be double as thick:

[image: Emoji appears to have a much thicker stroke]

As you can see the text's stroke is drawn as expected for a lineWidth of 1. The Noto bomb emoji however appears to have a much thicker stroke.

All characters in the screenshot are draw by the same strokeText and fillText call.

I'm doing this on the latest version of Google Chrome.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Edit:
Found the why, apparently the emoji's shape is a little more complex then you can see, drawing it a bit larger with a stroke width of 1 gives me this result:

[image: Shape is a little more complex then one might think]

For now I'll just do the stroke before doing the fill with a double stroke width as a quick fix. Please let me know if there's a proper way of working around this issue.